# Using decimals in GUI.Box in Unity C#

Tags: c#, user-interface, decimal, unity-game-engine

I have a question about C# in unity:

How come this code works:

```
GUI.Box(new Rect((Screen.width/2)-200,0,400,30) , "King of the hill");
```

While this one don't

```
GUI.Box(new Rect((Screen.width/2)-200,0,400.5,30) , "King of the hill");
```

The error I get is this:

```
The best overloaded method match for `UnityEngine.Rect.Rect(float, float, float, float)'   
has some invalid arguments
```

Doesn't this error imply that the GUI.Box takes float values? Why can't I use a decimal number.

Thanks in advance,
Spagnum

Comment: FYI 400.5 is a literal float. not a literal decimal, which would be 400.5M

Comment: @Surfbutler Actually 400.5 is a literal **double**, not float.

Comment: Yes, you're right (but definitely not a decimal anyway).

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that it doesn't know what 400.5 is.

try :

`GUI.Box(new Rect((Screen.width/2)-200,0,400.5f,30) , "King of the hill");`